# Using the command pattern for stored procedures

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Let's say that I have a application with objects like `Customer`, `Employee`, `Products` and `CountyOfResidence`. These objects map to tables in the database.

In the application we want to be able to search the database through a GUI with previously written stored procedures.

Is this a place where the command pattern would be useful?

Let's say we want to find out about the average age of our customers and employees.  With a little dynamic SQL in the stored procedure I can envision a situation something like
`FilterByAge(tableNameForDynamicSQL,typeWereFilteringAgainst)`.
Or something like `FindPercentileRank(subject,tableName,type)`.

The paradigm of using the GUI as the invoker and having the stored procedures as commands seems intuitive enough to me.  From those with practical experience, is this a pattern you would use in this situation?

Comment: "Let's say that I have a database with objects" did mean application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the command pattern doesn't return any results.  Usually, it is sending in a command to a system and allowing a class the encapsulate the intent of the command.

So, it doesn't fit your requirements exactly.  Your question is more about encapsulating queries.  However, I think you could encapsulate a query in the same way.

You might want to look at the [Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) pattern instead of Command.  Linq, itself, is a sort of Specification for a query (using Expressions).  So, if you are able to use something like Linq to SQL or Entity Framework, much of this is provided for you.

Comment: Yeah, I know that the entity framework does a lot of this type of stuff for you, but there's only so far I want to be away from the metal while I'm still learning.  This question was mainly theoretical to see if my mindset going in would be something others thought was a good idea..looks like it wasn't! :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie To me, your thinking seems fine.  You are looking for a way to encapsulate the task of querying.  I think that is a good thing as it will allow you to add more queries as you go without having to edit the existing queries.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing sounds like the [Query Object Pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html), which is very much like the command pattern, but it is specific to querying data or objects.

The level of customization that you are suggesting to allow has definite potential security and performance implications. For example, if an arbitrary table name can be sent to a stored procedure, and that query it builds runs against a table that is not tuned well for the SQL, then you run the risk of exposing a Denial-of-Service vector.

I had a similar requirement once, and what I found was that, though the search parameters needed to be altered, the return columns for any classification of queries (what you are referring to as "stored procedures") was always the same. I used this information to create a single type of Query Object for each set of return values. These allowed for extremely flexible queries that fully sanitized all input. It worked quite well.

As an aside, when building Query Object types, you are not limited to stored procedures. You can create parameterized SQL in code, and you can even build LINQ expression trees which you can run.

Answer (score 1):

> With a little dynamic SQL in the stored procedure

So your UI will simply be a "stored procedure parameter edit form", and all logic will be in the SP? I have been there, and wouldn't do that again soon.

I'd rather let my UI link to some business logic (outside of the database, but in a DLL or webservice that talks to the database), which can make up the appropriate database calls from certain input parameters.

This itself can again easily be done by using an ORM.

Comment: What types of problems did you have that would make you advice against it?  Is it just that the Entity Framework already exists and odds are I'm not going to do it better than Microsoft?

Comment: It's just that I personally extremely dislike business logic inside the database. The poor portability, crippled languages (try using string manipulation or arrays in an SP) and the total disconnection from your UI (for example for parameter validation) are things that bit me back when I did things that way.

Comment: So, you would say the fact that the data is filtered in the database with SQL and less data is sent over the wire is outweighed by returning a larger result set over the wire, and filtering it in the application layer?  I've dealt mainly with large datasets for research purposes and I'm timid about not letting my SQL do the work for me.  But, I've worked in smaller, isolated environments and haven't had to give as much thought to extensibility between RDBMS, etc.

Comment: I'm not talking about filtering on the client side, more about writing queries from code as opposed to passing a bunch of parameters and let the SP figure out what you want to query. :-)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Of course you want the database to do what it's good at: filtering, joining, ordering, etc, and you probably need dynamic SQL to do that. But why should that dynamic SQL be generated by a program in SQL? That's not what SQL was made for. And indeed there is fair chance that MS does a better job generating that dynamic SQL (with LINQ) than you would do. But the fact that you have a powerful general purpose language to write and control that logic is important too.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear.  When I said dynamic SQL what I really meant was replacing the table name of `Customers` with `Employee` where appropriate.  So let's say there's five joins in a query to pull together various data.  I would write a stored procedure where a parameter to the proc is the table name to join on, either Customers or Employees

Comment: I understand that, but as I said I prefer to do that from code.

Comment: @CodeCaster can you provide a quick example of how you would do something like that?  Maybe with columns like `Id` and `Name`.  I don't think I'm following you very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the command design pattern, there should be invoker, command and receiver, the store procedure should link to the receiver instead of the command.

The command could take a couple receiver in the constructor(which calls the store procedure) and then the receiver perform the actual task while the command is executing.